# Decimal limit jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

Anyone know how I can get the following to limit the decimals to 2 places? There's also a problem that it displays NaN when there are no values in the two fields (I'd rather it just show nothing). Can anyone help fix these problems?

HTML

```
<td class="grade">
    <input type="text" value="28" class="numerator" /> / <input type="text" value="30" class="denominator" />
    <div class="result"></div>
</td>
```

jQuery

```
function update($ele) {
    var n = Number($ele.find('.numerator')[0].value);
    var d = Number($ele.find('.denominator')[0].value);
    $ele.find('.result').text(n / d * 100);
}

$('.grade').each(function() {
    update($(this));
});

$('.grade input').on('keyup', function() {
    update($(this).closest('.grade'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPccV/1/)**:

```
function update($ele) {
    var n = Number($ele.find('.numerator')[0].value);
    var d = Number($ele.find('.denominator')[0].value);
    /* this works but is slightly more verbose (and maybe a bit slower) */
    var val = (n / d * 100);
    $ele.find('.result').text(( isNaN(val) || ! isFinite(val) ) ? '' : val.toFixed(2));
    /* This might be faster, and also make everything a bit more succinct * /
    var val = d !== 0 ? n / d * 100 : NaN;
    $ele.find('.result').text(isNaN(val) ? '' : val.toFixed(2));
    /* */
}
```

Comment: In addition to my original request, is it possible to stop showing 'infinity'? When you type a number into the .numerator field and leave the .denominator blank it shows the word 'infinity' - I'd rather it just show nothing.

Comment: Updated to take care of `Infinity` as well

Comment: Answer is correct by I'd suggest checking that `d` is not zero before doing the division (jslint).

Comment: @NabilKadimi I suppose that could probably make it faster. I added that option as a comment in the answer.

Comment: @kalley and as you said, "it will also make everything a bit more succinct"